# Detect the last element when using NSFastEnumeration?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, ios

Is it possible to detect the last item when using NSFastEnumeration?

```
for(NSString *str in someArray){

  //Can I detect if I'm up to the last string?

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is it possible to detect the last item
>   when using NSFastEnumeration?

Not with 100% accuracy (or by limiting the array contents to being entirely unique pointers so that pointer comparison works as discussed in another question) without also doing a bunch of work that leads to just doing it the old way.

Note that if you can target 4.0+, you can use `enumerateWithBlock:` that gives both the item and the index.  It is as fast or faster than fast enumeration, even.

Comment: In my case the pointers are unique, as they are coming from a filtered data source, but you are right.

Answer (score 2):

I think the only way is the old fashioned way, something like:

```
    NSUInteger count = [someArray count];
    for (NSString *str in someArray) {
         if (--count==0) {
              //this is the last element
         }
    }
```

Comment: Please explain the if statement. I don't understand the logic behind it.

Comment: `--count` decrements the value of `count` by one and evaluates to the decremented value. So overall it is equivalent to: `count-=1; if (count==0) { ... }`

Answer (score -1):

At the end of the loop, "str" will still be pointing to the last element.  What is it you need to do?

Comment: `str` won't exist outside the scope of the loop.

Comment: and even if `str` is defined before the loop to keep it in scope, it still won't work since `str` gets set to `nil` after the last iteration (see http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocFastEnumeration.html)